# Where should I put the common code of the constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a situation where in a class I have 2 constructors and they have very similar code. The only difference is the the call to the constructor of the super class. Where should I put this common code? I tried to use the instance block but with instance blocks I am not able to pass arguments required.

Also, the fields are final. So wont be able to initialize other then the constructor.

My code looks like:

```
private final SourceCache sourceCache;
private final ServiceCache serviceCache;
private final MethodCache methodCache;
private final ModelCache modelCache;
private final QueryFactory queryFactory;

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
    final Transaction transaction)
{
    super(transaction);
    this.transaction = transaction;
    this.sourceCache = new SourceCache(transaction);
    this.serviceCache = new ServiceCache(transaction);
    this.methodCache = new MethodCache(transaction);
    this.modelCache = new ModelCache(transaction);
    this.queryFactory = new QueryFactory();
    this.transaction.addQueryFactory(this.queryFactory);
}

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
    final Transaction transaction,
    final long fileSize)
{
    super(transaction, fileSize);
    this.transaction = transaction;
    this.sourceCache = new SourceCache(transaction);
    this.serviceCache = new ServiceCache(transaction);
    this.methodCache = new MethodCache(transaction);
    this.modelCache = new ModelCache(transaction);
    this.queryFactory = new QueryFactory();
    this.transaction.addQueryFactory(this.queryFactory);
}
```

Comment: another constructor that you call using `this()`

Comment: There are two general solutions for this problem: either do what @JackFlamp suggests and write a no-args constructor with all the common code or write a constructor with all parameters and call this constructor from all other constructors.

Comment: @Turing85 How would you combine call to `this` and call to `super`?

Comment: I wont be able to use Transaction then.

Comment: @lexicore you don't have to. Just have one of your constructors call `super(...)` and all other constructors call this constructor.

Comment: @Turing85 Sorry, replied to the wrong person.

Comment: @JackFlamp How would you combine call to `this` and call to `super`?

Comment: If there is some default `fileSize`, you could do leave the second constructor as it is and just call `this(transaction, fileSize);` from the first constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If your instance fields are final, I would just have the constructor without `filesize` just call the second one and pass in a `0`/`null` value.

Also, why are you assigning the transaction in the child class? Don't you pass it to the parent?

```
private final SourceCache sourceCache;
private final ServiceCache serviceCache;
private final MethodCache methodCache;
private final ModelCache modelCache;
private final QueryFactory queryFactory;

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
    final Transaction transaction)
{
    this(transaction, 0L); // Call the whole constructor below?
}

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
    final Transaction transaction,
    final long fileSize)
{
    super(transaction, fileSize);
    this.transaction = transaction; // Why are we setting this again?
    this.sourceCache = new SourceCache(transaction);
    this.serviceCache = new ServiceCache(transaction);
    this.methodCache = new MethodCache(transaction);
    this.modelCache = new ModelCache(transaction);
    this.queryFactory = new QueryFactory();
    this.transaction.addQueryFactory(this.queryFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move it to a private constructor.

EDIT:  Here is an example

```
public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
        final Transaction transaction) {
    super(transaction);
    this.transaction = transaction;
    MetaDataPersistenceHandler();
}

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
        final Transaction transaction,
        final long fileSize) {
    super(transaction, fileSize);
    this.transaction = transaction;
    MetaDataPersistenceHandler();
}

private void MetaDataPersistenceHandler(){

    this.sourceCache = new SourceCache(transaction);
    this.serviceCache = new ServiceCache(transaction);
    this.methodCache = new MethodCache(transaction);
    this.modelCache = new ModelCache(transaction);
    this.queryFactory = new QueryFactory();
    this.transaction.addQueryFactory(this.queryFactory);        
}
```

Comment: Tried. Was not able to use this with this approach.

Comment: @KaranKhanna Why not?

Comment: @KaranKhanna I updated my answer with an example.  Have you tried that?

Comment: The instance fields are final.

Comment: @KaranKhanna you should mention that the fields are final in the question.  That makes a big diff.

Comment: Added. Apologies for that.

Comment: @KaranKhanna not a problem.  I'm interested to see what answers you get now.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your effort here @JoseMartinez.

Comment: I added the final fields in your question so people are not lost... Feel free to correct the instance variables scope and visibility as you see fit.

Comment: You could move the common bits to a private constructor

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use Optional instead of 0 or null.

```
private final SourceCache sourceCache;
private final ServiceCache serviceCache;
private final MethodCache methodCache;
private final ModelCache modelCache;
private final QueryFactory queryFactory;

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
    final Transaction transaction)
{
    this(transaction, Optional.<Long>absent()); // Call the whole constructor below?
}

public MetaDataPersistenceHandler(
    final Transaction transaction,
    final Optional<Long> fileSize)
{
    super(transaction, (fileSize.isPresent() ? fileSize.get() : 0));
    this.transaction = transaction; // Why are we setting this again?
    this.sourceCache = new SourceCache(transaction);
    this.serviceCache = new ServiceCache(transaction);
    this.methodCache = new MethodCache(transaction);
    this.modelCache = new ModelCache(transaction);
    this.queryFactory = new QueryFactory();
    this.transaction.addQueryFactory(this.queryFactory);
}
```